# Music theory - secondary dominants

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-inversions, functional-harmony

Do i still have to use 1st inversion when using secondary diminished triads or sevenths?

I've been watching some videos but it didn't go over this.

Answer (score 1):

In common-practice music, diminished *triads* are basically *always* in first inversion. This means that any time you write a vii°—whether it's a regular vii° or a secondary diminished triad (like vii°/V)—it really needs to be in first inversion.

For fully diminished *seventh* chords, however, they can be in any inversion. Since this harmony is symmetrical (it's basically built of stacked minor thirds), all inversions technically sound exactly the same in twelve-tone equal temperament; the only difference is how they are spelled.

So in short, yes: any vii° triad needs to be in first inversion. But this rule does not apply to diminished seventh chords.